# Redirect Module doesn't redirect from node/{nid} to alias

Tags: 8, uri, redirection

I installed the [redirect Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect) in Drupal 8 but sorrily can't get it to work properly. I enabled all checkboxes in the settings, also the "Enforce clean and canonical URLs" option.

In my page source, the canonical is printed in a meta tag. But if I browse my page and enter a system URL like www.domain/node/5, no redirect to the autopath alias / canonical happens.

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions? I also reinstalled it twice already. Nothing helped.

Comment: Have you tried completly wiping cache? I had the same problem until I did a `drush cr` on command line

Comment: I just cleared the cache in the Backend UI, as this Drupal site sorrily doesnt have drush installed. Is there any possibility to wipe the cache completely without drush?

Comment: Clearing cache via Development > Performance is the same as full wipe via `drush cr`. If that didn't help it is a different problem.

Comment: Perhaps this needs to be implemented to get the features you need working: [Merge global redirect functions into Redirect module](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect/issues/905914).

Comment: Thanks @prkos, but this was only neccessary, before global redirects was merged with redirect module. The Drupal 8 version is a combination of those two modules. Anyways thanks - I already found out why it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

LEL - it's so stupid, I have to clarify this. The redirect module works without any problem. Everything's just like I wanted it. Maybe it's pointed out anywhere, but I didn't read it.

When the page is set to maintenance mode, it doesn't work. I have some dummy-users that can bypass the "maintenance-page" and use the site. While the site is in maintenance mode, the node/IDs are accessible. When I turned off maintenance mode, the module was redirecting...